# how to trigger validation on field which takes array as value in angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I want to trigger validation if speedArray  of object is empty.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mb-1" *ngIf="speed">
            <label for="speed" class="form-label">{{sharedLocale.speed}}<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <br>
            <div class="text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" (click)="editSpeedModel()">{{sharedLocale.add}}</button>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="speed.errors?.['required']">{{sharedLocale.speedRValidation}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Form**

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ItemListID: [itemListID, Validators.required],
      ItemID: [item.ItemID, Validators.required],
      group: [item.group, Validators.required],
      cost: [item.cost, Validators.required],
      description: [item.description, Validators.required],
      setup: [item.setup, Validators.required],
      speed: [Validators.required],
    });
```

**latter array get updated in form like this in Type Script**

```
onSubmit():void {
    if (this.myForm.invalid) {
      // trigger validation
      this.myForm.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }
this.myForm.get("speed")?.patchValue(this.speedArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator to check if the array is empty.

File `not-empty-array.validator.ts`

```
import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';

export function notEmptyArrayValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
  return Array.isArray(control.value) && control.value.length > 0 ? null : { emptyArray: true };
}
```

In your form declaration (remember to import the validator)

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      // same add the custom validator
      speed: [Validators.required, notEmptyArrayValidator],
    });
```

In your html template

```
<div class="mb-1" *ngIf="speed">
            <label for="speed" class="form-label">{{sharedLocale.speed}}<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <br>
            <div class="text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" (click)="editSpeedModel()">{{sharedLocale.add}}</button>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="speed.errors?.['required']">{{sharedLocale.speedRValidation}}</div>
                    <!-- add this control -->
                    <div *ngIf="speed.errors?.['emptyArray']">Array is empty!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```